# ASP.NET 4.0 Dropdownlist text coded in Chrome, Firefox

Tags: asp.net, css, drop-down-menu, rendering

I have an asp.net site which was developed with Visual Studio Pro 2010 with a  back-end of Windows Server 2008 R2 with SQL server 2008 R2 and II7 with Framework is 4.0

My Dropdownlist is working good only on IE, but not on chrome and firefox. The items are being displayed with weird characters, I am guessing that the output is encoded, so I just implemented a code to solve the issue but it seems that I am doing something wrong. See below by code.

Also I have tried with the legacy configuration just in case that is causing the problem, So I decided to put the following line on my web.config file.

web.config

```
<pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="3.5" clientIDMode="AutoID"/>
```

ASP.NET HTML TAG

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="JobCategoryList" runat="server"  OnDataBound="SortHTML">
    </asp:DropDownList>
```

Code Behind

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            DisplayCategories();
        }  
}

private void DisplayCategories()
    {
        _objCategories.getJobCategories();
        JobCategoryList.DataSource =         _objCategories.JobCategoriesDS.Tables["GetJobCategories"];
        JobCategoryList.DataTextField = "CategoryName";
        JobCategoryList.DataValueField = "Id";
        JobCategoryList.DataBind();
    }

protected void SortHTML(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (ListItem item in ((DropDownList)sender).Items)
        {
            item.Text = Server.HtmlDecode(item.Text);
        }
    }
```

Comment: can you please show what the render is (for this drop down list), or give us a live url for inspection ?

Comment: the is the url where the dropdownlist is displayed: http://www.strivepoint.com/Employers/NewAd.aspx

Comment: Aristos, please create a sample account, this is really important for me, I have been trying to solve this issue last two weeks and I am appreciate any help about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a css issue. In the `/css/normalize.css` locate this line, and remove ether the font family, ether the `select` from the list.

```
button,
input,
select,
textarea {
    font-family: inherit; /* 1 */ <--------- remove it
    font-size: 100%; /* 2 */
    margin: 0; /* 3 */
}
```

Also remove from `base.css` this wired fonts from this line also

```
/* Form defaults */
input[type="text"],
input[type="password"],
input[type="email"],
textarea,
select { 
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 6px 4px;
    outline: none;
    -moz-border-radius: 2px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    font-family: 'MuseoSans500Regular', Arial, sans-serif; <-------- remove it
    color: #777;
    margin: 0;
    width: 210px;
    max-width: 100%;
    display: block;
    background: #fff;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    }
```

You have place on drop down list this `MuseoSans500Regular` font name and this is made this wired bad design of the fonts.

You can ether change the font family, ether remove the `select` from this css lines, its up to you, but this is the issue.

Comment: Aristos, it works! thanks a lot for your time and support. I think I am going to sleep well tonight :-)